# How to customize structure instructions in vue

Tags: vue.js

In Angular, structural instructions can be used to control the rendering of elements. Can structural instructions be defined in Vue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Angular, but based on the Angular docs this sounds like conditional rendering using a computed property:

- [Vue - Conditional Rendering](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html)
- [Vue - Computed Property](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html)

For shared functionality across components I would start with Plugins or Mixins. Mixins are kind of an anti-pattern, but work well for smaller projects.

- [Vue - Plugins](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html)
- [Vue - Mixins](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html)

A more high-level approach is the Composition API (Vue 3), which allows a great number of customization for your components. A nice use-case could be reactive variables:

- [Vue - Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#reactive-variables-with-ref)

Comment: Structural instructions allow users to create the same instructions as `v-if` and `v-for`. For example, I can create a `v-unless` instruction that is the opposite of `v-if`

Comment: Ah ok I misunderstood. I'm not that deep into Vue3 but the closest thing is maybe Custom Directives. They are not exactly what you describe and not usable for loops AFAIK: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#custom-directives